# How can I import a module dynamically given its name as string?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm writing a Python application that takes a command as an argument, for example:

```
$ python myapp.py command1
```

I want the application to be extensible, that is, to be able to add new modules that implement new commands without having to change the main application source. The tree looks something like:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    commands/
        __init__.py
        command1.py
        command2.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

So I want the application to find the available command modules at runtime and execute the appropriate one.

Python defines an `__import__()` function, which takes a string for a module name:

> `__import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0)`
>
> The function imports the module `name`, potentially using the given `globals` and `locals` to determine how to interpret the name in a package context. The `fromlist` gives the names of objects or submodules that should be imported from the module given by `name`.
>
> Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__

So currently I have something like:

```
command = sys.argv[1]
try:
    command_module = __import__("myapp.commands.%s" % command, fromlist=["myapp.commands"])
except ImportError:
    # Display error message

command_module.run()
```

This works just fine, I'm just wondering if there is possibly a more idiomatic way to accomplish what we are doing with this code.

Note that I specifically don't want to get in to using eggs or extension points. This is not an open-source project and I don't expect there to be "plugins". The point is to simplify the main application code and remove the need to modify it each time a new command module is added.

---

<sub>**See also:** [How do I import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631)</sub>

Comment: What does the fromlist=["myapp.commands"] do?

Comment: @PieterMüller : in a python shell type this:  ``dir(__import__)``. The fromlist should be a list of names to emulate "from name import ...".

Comment: [Import module from string variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718885/import-module-from-string-variable)

Comment: As of 2019, you should look for `importlib`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956419/687896

Comment: Do not use  \_\_import\_\_ see [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)  use a [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

Answer (score 408, accepted):

With Python older than 2.7/3.1, that's pretty much how you do it.

For newer versions, see `importlib.import_module` for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

Or using `__import__` you can import a list of modules by doing this:

```
>>> moduleNames = ['sys', 'os', 're', 'unittest'] 
>>> moduleNames
['sys', 'os', 're', 'unittest']
>>> modules = map(__import__, moduleNames)
```

Ripped straight from [Dive Into Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20120315061111/http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/dynamic_import.html).

Comment: what is the differece to exec?

Comment: How could you use `__init__` of that module?

Comment: One problem with this solution for the OP is that trapping exceptions for one or two bad "command" modules makes his/her whole command-app fail on one exception. Personally I'd for loop over each __import__ individually wrapped in a try: mods=__import__()\nexcept ImportError as error: report(error) to allow other commands to continue to work while the bad ones get fixed.

Comment: Another problem with this solution, as Denis Malinovsky points out below, is that the python docs themselves recommend not using `__import__`. The 2.7 docs: "Because this function is meant for use by the Python interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
importlib.import_module()..." When using python3, the `imp` module solves this proble, as monkut mentions below.

Comment: fyi this is a funny "abuse" of map :) I wonder why python doesn't have thing like `foreach` though

Comment: @JohnWu why do you need `foreach` when you have `for element in` and `map()` though :)

Comment: I thought to save some time for all the people trying to use the autocomplete with dynamic modules with PyCharm. It doesn't work.

Comment: Note that the map will NOT work in python 3, since map now uses lazy evaluation.

Comment: @swhat but `modules = list(map(__import__, moduleNames))` should work, right?

Comment: And wouldn't `modules = list(map(importlib.import_module, moduleNames))` work just as well?

Comment: **Do NOT use `exec`**, _especially_ if you get your input from untrusted sources (such as user input). I can inject any code I want into `exec(f"import {sys.argv[1]}")`. Consider `sys.argv[1] = 'random; print("Do malware stuff")'`

Answer (score 403):

The [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) way for Python 2.7 and 3.1 and later is to use [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) module:

> **`importlib.import_module(`*****`name, package=None)`***
>
> Import a module. The name argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either `pkg.mod` or `..mod`). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be set to the name of the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. `import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg')` will import `pkg.mod`).

e.g.

```
my_module = importlib.import_module('os.path')
```

Comment: Recommended by which source or authority?

Comment: Documentation advises [against](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) using `__import__` function in favor of above mentioned module.

Comment: This works well for import `os.path` ; how about `from os.path import *`?

Comment: I get the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492879/248616 ie. calling `globals().update(my_module.__dict)`

Comment: @NamGVU, this is a dangerous method since it's polluting your globals and can override any identifiers with the same names.  The link you've posted has a better, improved version of this code.

Comment: additional question related to @NamGVU: what does importlib.import_module return? While "from my_module import func" makes error that "No module named 'my_module'", my_module.func() is working. How do you understand what my_module is?

Comment: The variable `my_module` is of `type` `module`, the same type as the result of `import os.path`.

Answer (score 137):

> Note: **imp** is deprecated since Python 3.4 in favor of **importlib**

As mentioned the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module provides you loading functions:

```
imp.load_source(name, path)
imp.load_compiled(name, path)
```

I've used these before to perform something similar.

In my case I defined a specific class with defined methods that were required.
Once I loaded the module I would check if the class was in the module, and then create an instance of that class, something like this:

```
import imp
import os

def load_from_file(filepath):
    class_inst = None
    expected_class = 'MyClass'

    mod_name,file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(filepath)[-1])

    if file_ext.lower() == '.py':
        py_mod = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)

    elif file_ext.lower() == '.pyc':
        py_mod = imp.load_compiled(mod_name, filepath)

    if hasattr(py_mod, expected_class):
        class_inst = getattr(py_mod, expected_class)()

    return class_inst
```

Comment: Good and simple solution. I'we written a similar one: http://stamat.wordpress.com/dynamic-module-import-in-python/ But your's has some flaws: What about exceptions? IOError and ImportError? Why not check for the compiled version first and then for the source version. Expecting a class reduces reusability in your case.

Comment: In the line where you construct MyClass in the target module you are adding a redundant reference to the class name. It is already stored in `expected_class` so you could do `class_inst = getattr(py_mod,expected_name)()` instead.

Comment: *Note that if a properly matching byte-compiled file (with suffix .pyc or .pyo) exists, it will be used instead of parsing the given source file*. [https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source)

Comment: Heads up: this solution works; however, the imp module is going to be deprecated in favor of import lib, see imp's page: """Deprecated since version 3.4: The imp package is pending deprecation in favor of importlib."""

Answer (score 49):

### Using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

#### Importing a source file

Here is a slightly adapted example [from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

```
import sys
import importlib.util

file_path = 'pluginX.py'
module_name = 'pluginX'

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)

# Verify contents of the module:
print(dir(module))
```

From here, `module` will be a module object representing the `pluginX` module (the same thing that would be assigned to `pluginX` by doing `import pluginX`). Thus, to call e.g. a `hello` function (with no parameters) defined in `pluginX`, use `module.hello()`.

To get the effect "importing" functionality `from` the module instead, store it in the in-memory cache of loaded modules, and then do the corresponding `from` import:

```
sys.modules[module_name] = module

from pluginX import hello
hello()
```

#### Importing a package

To import a package instead, calling `import_module` is sufficient. Suppose there is a package folder `pluginX` in the current working directory; then just do

```
import importlib

pkg = importlib.import_module('pluginX')

# check if it's all there..
print(dir(pkg))
```

Comment: add `sys.modules[module_name] = module` to the end of your code if you want to be able to `import module_name` afterwards

Answer (score 18):

Use the [imp module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_module), or the more direct [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function.

Comment: Do not use  \_\_import\_\_ see [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)  use a [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
exec("import myapp.commands.%s" % command)
```

Comment: How do I get a handle to the module through the exec, so that I can call (in this example) the .run() method?

Comment: You can then do getattr(myapp.commands, command) to access the module.

Comment: ... or add `as command_module` to the end of import statement and then do `command_module.run()`

Comment: In some version of Python 3+ __exec__ was converted into a function with the added benefit that the resultant referenced created in source get stored into the locals() argument of exec(). To further isolate the exec'd referenced from the local code block locals you can provide your own dict, like an empty one and reference the references using that dict, or pass that dict to other functions exec(source, gobals(), command1_dict)    .... print(command1_dict['somevarible'])

Comment: **Do not use `exec` or `eval` on data that could ever possibly come, in whole or in part, from outside of the program. It is a critical security risk. By doing this, you allow the creator of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer. It cannot easily be sandboxed, and ordinary attempts at sandboxes for these tools are usually still very vulnerable.**

Answer (score 12):

If you want it in your locals:

```
>>> mod = 'sys'
>>> locals()['my_module'] = __import__(mod)
>>> my_module.version
'2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'
```

same would work with `globals()`

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) for the built-in `locals()` function explicitly warns that the "contents of this dictionary should not be modified".

Comment: This doesn't add anything useful over previously existing answers; once the module has been imported (whether by the `import` statement, `__import__` builtin, an `importlib` library wrapper or anything else), it is a module object, and tasks like passing that object around, giving it a name, etc. are **not special**.

Answer (score 1):

Similar as @monkut 's solution but reusable and error tolerant described here http://stamat.wordpress.com/dynamic-module-import-in-python/:

```
import os
import imp

def importFromURI(uri, absl):
    mod = None
    if not absl:
        uri = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), uri))
    path, fname = os.path.split(uri)
    mname, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,mname)+'.pyc'):
        try:
            return imp.load_compiled(mname, uri)
        except:
            pass
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,mname)+'.py'):
        try:
            return imp.load_source(mname, uri)
        except:
            pass

    return mod
```

Answer (score 0):

The below piece worked for me:

```
>>>import imp; 
>>>fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module("/home/test_module"); 
>>>test_module = imp.load_module("test_module", fp, pathname, description);
>>>print test_module.print_hello();
```

if you want to import in shell-script:

```
python -c '<above entire code in one line>'
```

Answer (score -9):

The following worked for me:

```
import sys, glob
sys.path.append('/home/marc/python/importtest/modus')
fl = glob.glob('modus/*.py')
modulist = []
adapters=[]
for i in range(len(fl)):
    fl[i] = fl[i].split('/')[1]
    fl[i] = fl[i][0:(len(fl[i])-3)]
    modulist.append(getattr(__import__(fl[i]),fl[i]))
    adapters.append(modulist[i]())
```

It loads modules from the folder 'modus'. The modules have a single class with the same name as the module name. E.g. the file modus/modu1.py contains:

```
class modu1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=1
        print self.x
```

The result is a list of dynamically loaded classes "adapters".

Comment: Please don't bury answers without providing a reason in the comments. It doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I'd like to know why this is bad stuff.

Comment: Same as me, since I new to Python and want to know, why this is bad.

Comment: This is bad not just because it's bad python, but also it's just generally bad code.  What is `fl`?  The for loop definition is overly complex.  The path is hard coded (and for an example, irrelevant).  It's using discouraged python (`__import__`), what's all that `fl[i]` stuff for?   This is basically unreadable, and is unnecessarily complex for something that is not all that hard - see the top voted answer with its one-liner.

Comment: This is bad because it doesn't engage with the question as asked, and instead invents a bunch of new requirements to address.