# Dynamically importing a module and instantiating a class in Python

Tags: python, parsing, import

*My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python), though I'd like to go on step further.*

I'm parsing a configuration file which calls a number of actions (with parameters) by name. For example:

```
"on_click": "action1", "args": {"rate": 1.5}
```

Actions are python classes, inheriting from a base `Action` class, and can take named arguments. They're stored in an 'actions' subdirectory of the project, prefixed by an `a_`. I'd like to be able to add new actions by simply dropping a new file there, without having to change any other files. The project structure is like this:

```
myapp/
    actions/
        __init__.py
        baseaction.py
        a_pretty.py
        a_ugly.py
        ...
    run.py
```

All action classes provide a `PerformAction()` method and a `GetName()` method, which is what the configuration file refers to. In this example, `a_pretty.py` defines a class called `PrettyPrinter`. Calling `GetName()` on `PrettyPrinter` returns "action1".

I'd like to add the `PrettyPrinter` class to a dictionary with "action1" as the key, so I can instantiate new instances of it like the following:

```
args = {'rate': the_rate}
instantiated_action = actions['action1'](**args)
instantiated_action.PerformAction()
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
actions = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir("actions")
           if f.startswith("a_") and f.endswith(".py")]

for a in actions:

    try:
        module = __import__("actions.%s" % a, globals(), locals(), fromlist=["*"])
        # What goes here?
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

This is importing the action file, and if I print `dir(module)` I see the class names; I just don't know what I should be doing next (or if this whole approach is the correct way to go...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything in your `module` are classes that you should instanciate, try something like this :

for a in actions:

```
try:
    module = __import__("actions.%s" % a, globals(), locals(), fromlist=["*"])
    # What goes here?
    # let's try to grab and instanciate objects
    for item_name in dir(module):
        try:
           new_action = getattr(module, item_name)()
           # here we have a new_action that is the instanciated class, do what you want with ;)
        except:
           pass

except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't thought of using `getattr`.