# How to make from var_str import var_str in python

Tags: python, dynamic, import

Let me explain..

I want to do this:

```
a = "somedir.somefile"
b = "someclass"
from a import b
```

Well, I want to do this to import automatic all classes inside a directory, and I don't know how many classes are there.

Comment: Have you checked out this SO Post: [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Comment: Where did you get these strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "somedir.somefile"
b = "someclass"

module = __import__(a, globals(), locals(), [b], -1)
clazz = getattr(module, b)
```

now you can do this:

```
instance = clazz()
instance.method()
```

Comment: Works perfectly.. Thanks a lot!! It was awesome.. =D

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in function. It's a bit fiddly to use, though, because it returns the top-level module, rather than the leaf of the path. Something like this should work:

```
from operator import attrgetter
module_path = 'a.b.c'
class_name = 'd'

module = __import__(module_path)
attribute_path = module_path.split('.') + [class_name]
# drop the top-level name
attribute_path = attribute_path[1:]
klass = attrgetter('.'.join(attribute_path))(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want to do is use `__init__.py` and `__all__`. Take a look at the [modules tutorial](http://docs.python.org/release/2.1.3/tut/node8.html) for details.

Alternatively, there's `exec`. It will do what you're asking, but is probably not the best way to get there.