# Dynamic module loading in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

I have a list of modules, like so:

```
modules = ['ModuleA', 'ModuleB', 'ModuleC']
```

Each .py for the module resides in a subdirectory that I've added to the include paths. What I'm looking for is a way to load the modules and build a list of references to said loaded modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question:

```
references = map(__import__, modules)
```

or if you prefer dictionary with modules' names as keys:

```
references = dict(zip(modules, map(__import__, modules)))
```

Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
import importlib

imports = {}

for i in modules:
   imports[i] = importlib.import_module(i)
```

Watch out for `ImportError`s.

Comment: Nice solution, but works only since 3.1 (as [stated within documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/importlib.html#module-importlib)).