# How can I log the package name in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using Pythons `logging` module. I want to log the full path of a message, like
"msg packagename.modulename.functionName lineNumber", but how can I get the package name of a message?

The logging configuration is:

```
LOGGING = {    
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
    'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s [%(module)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d]'
    },  
},
'handlers': {
'console': {
        'level':'INFO',
        'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter':'simple',
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'develop': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

}

and I get a logger like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('develop')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'package name' which is different from what `%(module)s` produces?

Comment: As of Python 3 (>=3.6, at least), it can be achieved with a simple filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72873684/687896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions to the problem.

One, pass in the filename with every call to log.[debug,info,error,...] as obtained by the `__file__` magic variable. This does not give you the package name, but it's as good as that for finding out where the log message originated. The downside is that you'd need to modify every logging call in your application.

Two, make a subclass of `logging.Logger` which overrides the `Logger.log` instance method. In your new `log` method, use the `inspect.stack()` and `inspect.getframeinfo()` methods to find the stack frame which caused the call to `log` in your code and extract filename and line numbers. You can then modify the log message which was passed in accordingly. Finally, tell the `logging` module to use your subclass by calling `logging.setLoggerClass()`.

Comment: because I've using log4j for a long time, I'm curious that how to know where a error message occur without package name?

Comment: `__file__` gets you the absolute path of the python source file from which the current module was compiled.

Comment: oh, yes, that's really a solution.

Comment: As of today, filter would do it (too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/72873684/687896

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to get a "package name" like Java does by default, but to add the filename (which gives you just as much context), use `%(pathname)s` in your format string:

```
'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(message)s [%(pathname)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d]'
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend generating your package's logger with `logging.getLogger(__name__.split('.')[0])`, configure it with a formatter that includes the `name` parameter and then generate your module's logger with `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

For example:

```
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

package_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__.split('.')[0])
package_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
package_logger.addHandler(handler)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('message')
```

For a module `module.py` located inside of a package named `package`, the `logger.info()` call should generate the following message to `STDERR`:

```
package.module - message
```

Inside of other modules within the same package, you can simply setup your logger as follows to get similar functionality to work in it:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('another message')
```

For a module `another.py` inside of the package `package`, called from the `module.py` module of the same package, this should generate the following text to `STDERR`:

```
package.another - another message
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a utils.py file inside a package called common and it has the below.

*utils.py*

```
import logging
log = logging
log.basicConfig(level=log.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(filename)s:%(funcName)s'
                                       ':%(levelname)s :%(message)s')
```

In any other file that I need to use the log, i use the below.

```
from pkg.common.utils import log
log.info("some msg")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how I implemented this:
https://github.com/JensTimmerman/vsc-base/blob/master/lib/vsc/utils/fancylogger.py

as Simon suggests, I extended to python logger to add custom fields. 
But you can also just define a new getLogger function that does this:

```
rootmodulename = inspect.stack()[-1][1].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
callingfunctionname = inspect.stack()[2][3]
logger = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (rootmodulename, callingfunctionname))
```

But look into fancylogger.py for a complete worked out example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we're talking about the same thing. My issue now was that I wanted to have precise indication of where each message was being logged (especially in DEBUG mode).

**TL;DR**: add a simple `filter` to your handler:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#imparting-contextual-information-in-handlers

, through which you can modify the current LogRecord (with the package/module's path, for instance).

---

**Example**

My lib is called `npt`, and some message is being logged inside the module `npt/search/_ode.py`, inside the function "parse" more precisely. I want to have this information in my log messages: the function name, module name, and the (sub)packages where the module is. Something like "`INFO: npt.search._ode.parse(): file <whatever> parsed`"

The formatter provides lots of attributes (see [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)), of interest here, for instance (from the docs):

- pathname: Full pathname of the source file where the logging call was issued (if available). E.g, `/Users/chbrandt/repos/npt/npt/search/_ode.py`.
- filename: Filename portion of pathname. E.g, `_ode.py`.
- module: Module (name portion of filename). E.g, `_ode`.

There is *not* a *single* parameter that provides the *relative* path of the module *inside* the library only; `pathname` will log the absolute path of the module in your system (we don't wanna do that, right). But it is useful to get what you want, obviously, we just have to cut the *absolute* part of the path.

So, what I did was: I initialize my log/handler at the very top of my package, inside `npt/_log.py`, call it `log`, and use `from npt import log` everywhere inside `npt`. During logging setup, I get the path of `npt` inside the system, and then define a `filter()` function where an attribute `package` is added to the record with the *relative* path of my module *inside* my library (npt).

Here is the code I currently have:

```py
import logging

# Get the current path (/path/to/lib/npt/_log.py) from __file__
# and compute the size of the string up-until npt's position
#
from pathlib import Path
_lib_path = Path(__file__).parents[1]
_leng_path = len(_lib_path.as_posix())

def filter(record: logging.LogRecord):
    # I'm using the _leng_path because is simple/fast,
    # just chop the system path from `pathname`.
    # Define `package` attribute with the relative path.
    record.package = record.pathname[_leng_path+1:]
    return record

# Notice `package` attribute, which is adhoc inside `filter()`
fmt="%(levelname)s: [%(name)s - %(package)s] %(funcName)s: %(message)s"

# Then...proceed as usual...

log = logging.getLogger('npt')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(filter)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

Now I have messages like:

```py
> import npt
> df_search = npt.search.ode(dataset=dataset, product_id=pid)
INFO: [npt - npt/search/_ode.py] parse: 1 products found
```

Which solves the issue perfectly for my/this case.

Comment: what if I want this for all my files in the application but do not have a single root package for alle code files? Do I need to create n such  _log.py files for every of the n packages?

Comment: @Kaspatoo It depends on the structure of files in your application, and what you want to achieve. If you want to use this code as it is, without modifications, then _yes_, you'd copy it to the N packages you have. That would log the relative path inside _each package_. If you want, instead, to log the relative path inside _the application_ then you just have to have this module in a path common to all the packages (eg, the app's root); you just have to put such path in your PYTHONPATH env. variable (the code would still work as it is, as far as I can see).

Comment: @Kaspatoo check also this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956419/687896 . I don't know if I understood correctly your case, maybe useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just use style '{' with {module} as explained https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/

Example:

```
'formatters': {
    'standard': {
        'format': '{asctime}: [{levelname}] [{name}] [{module}.{funcName} linenr: {lineno}]: {message}',
        'style': '{',
    },
    'report': {
        'format': '{asctime}: [{name}.{module}.{funcName} linenr: {lineno}]: {message}',
        'style': '{',
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '{levelname} {message}',
        'style': '{',
    },
},
```