# python: Importing modules in project using dynamic naming

Tags: python

My project layout looks like:

```
run.py
jobs/
   job1.py
   job2.py
```

`job1.py` is pretty basic:

```
class job1():

    def __init__(self):
        print 'yo'
```

In run.py, I have:

```
name = 'job1'
classname = 'jobs.%s' % name
__import__(classname)
```

Which obviously does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    __import__(classname)
ImportError: No module named jobs.job1
```

What is the best way to import the modules in this manner?

Comment: Why? do you "really" want to do imports like this?

Comment: So I can easily add the modules by putting their classes in the `jobs` directory.

Comment: This is very similar to [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python). And as [Ashwini Chaudhary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125074/python-importing-modules-in-project-using-dynamic-naming#11125112) explains below, you are probably simply missing an `__init__.py` file in your jobs folder to make it a package.

Answer (score 2):

first of all create a `__init__.py` file inside jobs folder, to make this `jobs.jobs1` thing work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `__init__.py` in `jobs` directory

```
import os
jobs = {}
for module in (name for name in os.listdir(".") if name.endswith(".py")):
    jobs[module] = __import__(module)
```

Then just use it like this

```
from jobs import jobs
```