# how to pass value of a variable to import statement in python

Tags: python, string, import, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I'm really new to python. **I'm using python<2.7.** I have to import a file whose name I don't know at start. In fact I have to pass the name of file through command prompt, now I have read the name and stored in variable, but I don't know how to pass it to import statement. I'm trying the code

```
str = sys.argv[lastIndex]
from "%s" import *,str
```

but it's giving the error

```
File "IngestDataToMongo.py", line 86
from "%s" import *,str
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how to do it. Also is it possible with python <2.7, because for some reasons I can't change the version of Python or install anything where this code is running.

Comment: you should refer to dynamic module imports http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to import the `importlib` module, this does it:

```
import sys
s = sys.argv[lastIndex]
def is_save(s):
    #test if s is a valid argument
    return True or False

if is_save(s):
    exec('from %s import *'%s)
```

Note: the `is_save` function is needed to avoid abuse of the script since the usage of `exec` (or `eval`) is [potentially dangerous](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/).

Comment: hey man, you are great, This worked perfectly, and with only 1 line of code. Thousand thanks to you. I'm your fan now.

Comment: I can't recommend this version in cases where the imported argument might be unsafe (i.e. come from a user you may not trust). In general `exec` and `eval` should be avoided, since it's difficult to make sure that the string passed to these functions is sane. The use of `importlib` or `__import__` is definitely recommend.

Comment: @DavidZwicker I agree with you and modified the answer to avoid the passage of potentially insane strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function instead to import modules. It accepts variables as its arguments.

But first of all, make sure you really need that - 90% of the time people do not really need that function.

Comment: I think it is more like 99%.

Comment: @sberry: Maybe, but the metaclasses are something that people do not need 99% of the time, and I think `__import__()` is really useful to a bigger number of people, so I picked 90% instead of 99% ;) Anyway, no real data behind it.

Comment: 83 percent of statistics are made up on the spot.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Yeah, we got it :) It is nice you introduced some real data to the discussion ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html?highlight=importlib#importlib) module

```
import importlib

mdl = 'urllib'
your_module = importlib.import_module(mdl)
your_module.quote
>>> <function urllib.quote>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Tadeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548696/tadeck) - This does work for python 2.7 and 3.1+

Comment: One important note: `importlib` is not available in Python <2.7, nor 3.0, and even in 2.7 it is "_a minor subset of what is available in the more full-featured package of the same name from Python 3.1_" ([source](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html)).

Comment: @Tadeck seeing your comment I have to edit my question, because I have to use python 2.6