# python: how to call a constructor in a module in a package in another package directly

Tags: python, python-module

I am porting some matlab code to python. I need to work with packages and modules in this case. The relevant package directory structure looks like this:

```
toppackage
    __init__.py
    subpackage
        __init__.py
        module.py
        ...
```

In the script I use the package, I can work like this:

```
from toppackage.subpackage.module import SomeClass
s = SomeClass()
```

But I would prefer working like this:

```
import toppackage %somewhere at the beginning of file
s = toppackage.subpackage.module.SomeClass()
```

I see this is done in numpy. But I could not find it in documentation. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import contained packages in the `__init__.py` files.

You can import the packages inside the `toppackage/__init__.py` for example:

```
import toppackage.subpackage.module
```

or you can import just each directly contained package, so in `toppackage/__init__.py`:

```
from . import subpackage
```

and in `toppackage/subpackage/__init__.py`:

```
from . import module
```

Just importing the top-level package does not automatically make the contained packages available. You need to explicitly import the full path once, somewhere, before that works.

The `numpy` package imports the nested packages in the top-level `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yes, this works. However this package is in fast development stage, and I expect frequent subpackage changes for modules. It may be cumbersome to remember editing `subpackage/__init__.py` each time. I tried `from . import *` but it does not work. 

As a possible workaround, can we do this: We can easily find the modules in a subpackage programmaticaly. Assuming variable `module_name` has the name of a module, can we import it?

Comment: @ozi: You only need to import modules that are not automatically imported indirectly already. Say `module` imports `from . import utils`, then `utils` is now imported and reachable already. This is not as big a problem as you think it is.

Comment: Probably it is not a big problem. Still, I found ways to load the modules dynamically after you get their path programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Comment: Sure there are, but in my opinion that'd be overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

How this stuff works depends critically on what is in `__init__.py`.  Whatever gets imported in that script becomes part of the package namespace.

For example, if your `toppackage/__init__.py` is empty, to gain access to `subpackage`, you'd need to do:

```
import toppackage
try:
    p = toppackage.subpackage
except AttributeError:
    print "you would see this"

import toppackage.subpackage
p = toppackage.subpackage #no error now
```

however, if `toppackage/__init__.py` included the line:

```
#toppackage/__init__.py
import subpackage
```

Then the above script would raise no Exceptions.

As noted in the comments, you can also use relative imports since you are in a package:

```
from . import subpackage
```

This avoids "namespace" conflicts -- e.g. if you have a subpackage named `os` it will get your subpackage rather than the python-level package.

Comment: Better not use relative imports; `from . import subpackage` would be preferable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- But that breaks compatibility with python2.4 ;-)

Comment: Do we care about 2.4 that much anymore? 2.6 and up, is what I normally assume. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I was mostly just kidding around.  I added that.  If memory serves correctly, I believe I've even seen `import toppackage.subpackage as subpackage`.  That's actually the form I use inside the submodules themselves, but I'm not sure that I've used it in an `__init__.py` before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- In any event, from the standpoint of explaining *how* to manipulate a package's namespace, I like the first form as then you don't need to explain the magic of relative imports.  Although, in this case, I would say that the "explicit" relative import is probably best as you pointed out.