# How can I dynamically import in Python?

Tags: python

I'm totally new with Python,can anyone please let me know how I can do the following two imports in a python script followed by the other line WHILE i IS BEING CHANGED IN EACH LOOP?
(The following three lines are in a "for" loop whose counter is "i")

```
import Test_include_i
from Test_include_i import*
model = Test_include_i.aDefinedFunction
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is.... Such a terrible idea.

Comment: why would you want that ? :O

Comment: Check answer of this question. [Dynamic module import in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Comment: To defend the OP a bit, there are use-cases for this, which you can see by the naming of the variables. He/She might want to elaborate, but having a bunch of similar models implemented in one `.py` file each is not such a bad idea.

Comment: @rnbcoder I am actually reading some information from a file named Test_include,which is being changed in each loop.And I want each loop to import the latest Test_include,so I am renaming it each time.If it is possible to somehow REFRESH the "import Test_include" command,then I can delete "_i" at the end of its name!

Comment: @filmor Thank you,I am actually reading some parameters of the model of a tunnel from the Test_include file,which is being changed in each loop,and I need the loop to load the latest Test_include file actually! :)

Comment: Use `imp.reload()` to force a reload of a module.

Comment: @user2614391 no i meant why `import Test_include_i` and then 
`from Test_include_i import*` ?

Comment: I have absolutely no logical answer for this,as long as this file is just a small part of a really big problem in which I can not go deeper for numerous dependencies!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a good idea, but this is the implementation of it:

```
from importlib import import_module # Awesome line! :)

for i in range(1000):
    test_include = import_module("Test_include_%s" % i)
    model = test_include.aDefinedFunction
```

Regarding the differences between the provided methods:

- `__import__` is the low-level interface that handles `from bla import blubb` and `import bla` statements. It's direct use is according to the docs discouraged nowadays.
- `importlib.import_module` is a convenience wrapper to `__import__` which is preferred. The imported module will be recorded in `sys.modules` and thus be cached. If you changed the code during the session and want to use the new version you have to reload it explicitly using `imp.reload`.
- `imp.load_module` is even closer to the internals and will always load the newest version of the module for you, i.e. if it is already loaded `load_module` is equivalent to a `imp.reload` call on the module. However to use this function you have to provide all 4 arguments, which are basically what `imp.find_module` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much,the concept was really helpful but unfortunately I do not have this library!

Comment: It was added in Python 2.7.  For earlier versions, use `__import__` instead.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower: Oh,thank you very much,I will do it,I did not know! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function, and perhaps [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html), although you should consider if that's what you really want to do.  Perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve, and there will probably be a better way.

Comment: I think the importlib library should work,however,unfortunately the Python with which I am working is 2.6.6 and does not have this library!
I am reading some information from Test_include file in each step which is being changed and renamed (by adding i at the end of its name),so in each step I have to import the latest edited file,not the previous one.
I can also add that it is not important for me if the previous Test_include files are kept or not! :)

Comment: If you're using Python 2.6.6, then the `imp` module would be your best option (see my answer below). I would not use `__import__`, as this is a low-level implementation which is not intended to be used in "production" code. There is a reason for the `imp` module :)

Comment: That's backwards -- `imp` is the low-level implementation interface that provide access to the internals, and usually requires multiple calls to do things right (find followed by load).  Using the documented `__import__` API is perfectly fine.

Comment: @user2614391 if that's all you want, then take a look at [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#reload)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imp.load_module()`, which accepts a string as module name. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module

Comment: Thank you very much,it was a really great help! :)
It worked with "imp.reload(Test_include)" and I do not have to change the name of the Test_include file in each loop any more!