# How to convert strings to variables for import? python

Tags: python, syntax, import, global

I can use the following code to change a string to a variable and then call function of the library that was previously imported.

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = 'sys'
>>> globals()[x]
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> globals()[x].__doc__
```

Without first importing the module, I have an string to variable but I can't use the same `globals()[var]` syntax with `import`:

```
>>> y = 'os'
>>> globals()[y]
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> import globals()[y]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import globals()[y]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> z = globals()[y]
>>> import z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named z
```

**Is it possible for a string input and import the library that has the same name as the string input?** If so, how?

@ndpu and @paulobu has answered that `__import__()` allows string to library access as a variable. But is there a problem with using the same variable name rather than using an alternate for the library? E.g.:

```
>>> x = 'sys'
>>> sys = __import__(x)
```

Comment: I don't think so, it also might be a good approach to avoid confusion. I'll update my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Python coders prefer using [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead of `__import__`:

```
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> mod = raw_input(":")
:sys
>>> sys = import_module(mod)
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.version_info # Just to demonstrate
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>>
```

You can read about the preference of `importlib.import_module` over `__import__` [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#__import__).

Comment: +1 Is true that `import_module` is more recommendable.

Comment: @alvas - Because `__import__` is a very advanced built-in that is mainly used to customize the way Python imports modules.  If your goal is simply to import a module from a string, it is better to use a function built explicitly for that.  Note however that this is a _preference_ of Python coders.  Kinda like how list comprehensions are generally preferred over functional programming with `map`.  You can still use `__import__` if you really want to. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `__import__` function:

```
x = 'sys'
sys = __import__(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) built-in function:

```
__import__(globals()[y])
```

Basic usage:

```
>>>math = __import__('math')
>>>print math.e
2.718281828459045
```

You can also look into `importlib.import_module` as suggested in another answer and in the `__import__`'s documentation.