# error dynamically importing and calling module in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble getting the two following examples to work together, [dynamically loading a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python) and  [calling a function by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python). I'm trying to dynamically load and call python modules.

My file structure is as follows

```
src/
    main.py
    __init__.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
        ...
        module100.py
```

In my main.py function I have the following to load the module,

```
mod = imp.load_source('module', '/path/to/module.py')
```

This seems to be working fine, `print module` yields

```
<module 'module' from '/path/to/module.py'>
```

In `module.py` I have

```
class module:

    def __init__(self):
        print ("HELLO WORLD")

    def calc(self):
        print ("calc called")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        sys.exit(not main(sys.argv))
```

The problem is when I try to call the calc function in module,

```
result = getattr(module, 'calc')()
```

yields the following

```
  HELLO WORLD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in main
    result = getattr(module, 'calc')()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'calc
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing or doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason you named your class `module` too, which is confusing you.

Your `module` is, well,  a module:

```
>>> mod = imp.load_source('module', 'module.py')
>>> mod
<module 'module' from 'module.pyc'>
>>> dir(mod)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'module']
```

Your class is `mod.module`:

```
>>> x = mod.module()
HELLO WORLD
>>> x
<module.module instance at 0xa1cb18c>
>>> type(x)
<type 'instance'>
```

Aside: the line

```
    self
```

doesn't do anything, and your `calc` method will need to accept an argument, or you'll get `TypeError: calc() takes no arguments (1 given)` when you call it.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, but I don't see how this solves my problem. how can i call the class dynamically? won't I have to change mod.module() to something else every time?

Comment: or i could keep the class name the same in all the files but the functions different i suppose