# How do I import another python file provided as command-line-argument?

Tags: python

This is what `a.py` looks

```
import sys


def test_import(another_python_file):
    import another_python_file as b
    b.run_me()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.argv
    test_import(sys.argv[1].strip())
```

this is what `b.py` looks

```
def run_me():
    print 'I am script b'
```

When I run, I get

```
$ python a.py b.py
['a.py', 'b.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 10, in <module>
    test_import(sys.argv[1].strip())
  File "a.py", line 5, in test_import
    import another_python_file as b
ImportError: No module named another_python_file
```

**What I need?** 
I would expect it to import `b.py` and print `I am script b`

What am I missing?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
a.py:

import os
import sys


def test_import(another_python_file):
    b = __import__(another_python_file)
    b.run_me()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.argv
    test_import(sys.argv[1].strip('.py'))

b.py
def run_me():
    print 'I am script b'

$ python a.py b.py
['a.py', 'b.py']
I am script b
```

I was able to do that referring to http://www.diveintopython.net/functional_programming/dynamic_import.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need flexibility, you can simply use `__import__('module_name')`. If you need advanced features like cache control, module searching or reloading, use [the imp module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html).