# Python: select packages to import in runtype [dynamically]

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have APIs [port.py] with the same interface for two different hardware platforms: mips and powerpc. By the same interface I mean that classes are the same, thier methods are the same, but implementation differs.

```
mips/port.py
powerpc/port.py
```

A program that uses these APIs should be decoupled from the specific platform and the code looks exactly the same except importing packages. How is it possible to dynamically select the platform, something like the code below, where `platform` is a global setting (`mips` or `powerpc`) or whatever like this:

```
from [platform].port import PortCli
```

I tried importing with `if`, but it looks nasty and doesn't scale well since I may need to add a different platform.

Thank you

Update after discussion with Eduard:

The code below is actually an analogue of `import mips.port`:

```
import importlib
platform = 'mips'
myModule = importlib.import_module(platform + '.port')
myModule.Port().PrintMe()
```

It's fine, but I need to add myModule everywhere. Is it possible to have a similar substitute for `from mips.port import Port`?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Comment: I went through it before, can you please recommend what would work in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [post](http://asvetlov.blogspot.ru/2010/05/blog-post.html) of Python Core Developer Andrey Svetlov.

I can suggest you to add platform/hardware specific Python modules in separate directories and append this modules to `sys.path` in runtime.

For example:
We have a package

- package

  - __init__.py
  - a.py
  - x86_64

    - b.py
  - i386

    - b.py

`__init__.py` will contain something like this:

```
import sys
import platform
from os.path import join, dirname
__path__.append(join(dirname(__file__), platform.machine()))
```

With this approach common code is located in package while platform specific distributed in subdirectories.

Take attention that `x86_64` and `i368` do not have `__init__.py` module.

Import required module `b`

```
from package import b
```

Comment: Hello Eduard, thanks for the reply. I'm actually building software that tests functionality of various platforms so I execute it on x86 comp. Is it possible to supply what platform I test as a variable or whatever to `__init__.py`. I think it's about changing of `platform.machine()` for some global variable or something like this

Comment: You can pass it through environment variable or read it from configuration files.

Comment: I work on x86 computer and I run remote tests (using telnet, com) on `mips` and `powerpc` platforms. I want to pass `mips/powerpc` as a parameter to the test software. It has nothing to do with `platform.machine()` as you may see

Comment: In this case my answer do not fits your needs. Just pass platform as a command line argument and make conditional import.

For example

    platform = sys.argv[1]
    if platform == 'mips':
        import mips.port as port
    elif platform == 'powerpc':
        import powerpc.port as port

    port.run_tests()

WBR

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I tried the approach with `if/elif`. It works, but it's not good, since if I add a third platform, I'll have to change a LOT of files in my program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49467/discussion-between-eduard-iskandarov-and-konstantin)