# Import scripts and execute the one the user needs

Tags: python, function, command-line, import

i have three scripts, they are all write as one or several functions
and i have this other script which imports them, but when i run it, it runs the three other scripts (one after another)

```
import script1
import script2
import script3
#import sys 
#he i have some other lines but they just dont work

in=raw_input("write python+name_of_this_file+name_of_the_function")
#i do not know how to continue
```

what can i do to run this script and execute just the file the user wants, i do not know to much about python (does three script took me a lot to make them)
thank you in advance

Comment: This question is related to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to dynamically import a python module and call one if it's functions?

Use `importlib.import_module()`. Example,

```
import importlib

response = raw_input("Please type module_name function_name: ")
module_name, function_name = response.split()
print "User entered module_name %r, function_name %r" % (module_name, function_name)

try:
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    result = getattr(module, function_name)()
    print "%s.%s() returned %r" % (module_name, function_name, result)
except ImportError, e:
    print "Failed to import module %r" % module
except AttributeError, e:
    print "Function %r not found in module %s" % (function_name, module_name)
```

Comment: thanks i guess this is exausting for someone who knows about python,  thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the content of script1.py, script2.py and script3.py. I am guessing that there is top-level code in each module which is being executed, and that you don't want that to happen.

Code in a module will be executed when it is imported. For example, if script1.py contains this:

```
# script1.py
def f():
    print "not called on import"

# following will be executed on first import
print "print was executed"
x = 10
print x * x
```

Importing it will result in this:

```
>>> import script1
print was executed
100
```

The code in the function was not executed, but the statements declaring the function were.

You can prevent execution of the top level code on import by checking the `__name__` variable like this:

```
# script1.py
def f():
    print "not called on import"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # following will NOT be executed on first import, only if run directly
    print "print was executed"
    x = 10
    print x * x

>>> import script1
>>> script1.f()
not called on import
```

But, if `script1.py` is executed directly the printed content will appear:

```
$ python script1.py
print was executed
100
```

The other part of your question was how a user could invoke functions that are declared in your three script files?? You could use `input()` rather than `raw_input()` and have the user enter the string `script1.f()` for example.

```
# main.py
import script1
import script2
import script3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input("write <module_name>.<name_of_the_function>() : ")

$ python main.py 
write <module_name>.<name_of_the_function>() : script1.f()
not called on import
```

Comment: hello, i have no a top-level code, the three scripts contain functions i just need to write python+code_that_imports+script1(or 2 or 3) and that this run the script the user choosed

Comment: i tried the last block but it still runs the the three scripts one after the other

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you are trying to do. There is a difference between running a python script file and importing a python module. Are you trying to execute the script (e.g. script1.py) by starting a new python process (i.e. a subprocess), or are you wanting to dynamically import a user specified module (e.g. script1) and then execute one of the functions stored in that module?

Comment: i  want to execute the script like the one of the question and the user has to choose which script (1,2 or 3) has to be executed, i guess this is -dynamically import a user specified module and execute all the functions in that module- sorry for not being clear, anyway, thanks for your time

Comment: I've added an answer for "dynamically importing a module and calling __one__ of it's functions". If you want to execute __all__ of it's functions you'd be best off creating a single function for each module that calls each of the functions within the module. It's also possible to use introspection (see the inspect module), but that's more difficult.