# Can i use for loop to import model classes?

Tags: python, django, loops

Suppose here is my models.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import *

# Create your models here.

class A(models.Model):
    p = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    d = models.OneToOneField(User)
    e = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    f = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    g = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name="c")
```

i wanto import these models inside my views like this.

```
from app import models
def import():
    list=['A','B','C']

    for x in list:
        from model import x

import()
```

Please suggest me a better solution ,I am new to python django.Thanks in advance.

edit

i want to use this loop for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Better to just import the models file itself and reference them from there.

```
from my_app import models

models.A.objects.all()
models.B.objects.all()
```

Avoid `from my_app import *`: it can lead to confusion and namespace pollution, plus explicit is better than implicit.

But of course if you already know the list of models, you can simply import those directly:

```
from my_app.models import A, B, C
```

Comment: what if there is more classes like A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I....... so this list could help me na?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question. Either of the approaches I show would work with any number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this answer suggested
[Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

```
import imp
import os

def load_from_file(file path, expected_class):
 class_inst = None


 mod_name,file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(filepath)[-1])

 if file_ext.lower() == '.py':
     py_mod = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)

 elif file_ext.lower() == '.pyc':
     py_mod = imp.load_compiled(mod_name, filepath)

 if hasattr(py_mod, expected_class):
     class_inst = getattr(py_mod, expected_class)()

 return class_inst
```

i.e

```
 module = load_from_file(file_path, expected_class)
```

Comment: No need for this at all: OP is trying to import classes from within a single module, not dynamically import modules.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that you are trying to import all classes of models in your views file

simple way is:

```
from app.models import *
```