# How to get variables from another file in python

Tags: python

For example I have a variable `config` in `config.py`. I want to use the variable `config` in `main.py`. **And the `config.py` must be pass to `main.py` through command line**. like follows:

```
python ./main.py ./config.py
```

I know in `lua` I can use `dofile` function. How can I do this in `Python`

Fixed by [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: i cant comment

can you just import the variable in main.py ?

```
from .config import config

#do stuff
```

the only other way i could imagine this would work, if you would pipe the line to the main.py file and parse it by hand or something:

```
cat config.py | grep 'config = ' | sed -e 's,config = ,,g' | python main.py
```

thou this will only work if config is only used once in the file and the value it represents is behind the = and you know if it is a string or a int etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
# main.py
import sys
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    var_name = "config"
    arg = sys.argv[1]
    module_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(arg))
    if module_path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, module_path)

    module_name = os.path.basename(arg).replace(".py", "")
    module = __import__(module_name)
    config_var = getattr(module, var_name)
    # use config_var
```