# Loading a directory full of decoder modules

Tags: python, class, classloader

[TL;DR]  Thanks to Alexi - I have a working solution below

I'm trying to figure out Python Classes and inheritence so that I can create a protocol decoder package.

The package needs to work as follows:

- I get a directory full of data files.
- My python code inspects each file, and determines a protocol id number.
- Based on the protocol_id I can calculate (yes, calculate) the file name of the specific decoder.
- If the decoder filename does not exist, I choose some default name
- Need help here: I have the filename in a variable how do I load it?

I've done this before in C code, with Shared Objects, I'm trying create something similar using python.

Part #1 Pseudo code is like this:

```
def GetDecoderViaId( idnumber ):
    filename = "all_decoders/protocol_%04x.py" % idnumber

    # Pseudo code use default if special is not found
    if (! os.access(filename,os.R_OK)):
        filename = "all_decoders/protocol_DEFAULT.py"

    # Question #1 How do I do this
    # Where each "filename" is a python class.
    theclass = import_by_filename( filename )
    return theclass
```

Part #2 - The decoders need to come from a common base class. I have done simple classes, but what does not work is when I try to load them using various techniques I have found via google. I can load something, I just can't seem to call the decoder.

Question#2 How do I do that?

My Decoder Base Class looks like this:

```
 # Simple base class
 def DecoderBase(object):
    def __init__(id,name,compatlist):
       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.compatiblelist = compatlist

    def Decode( bytes, byte0, byteN ):
       """ Default is just a hex dump """
       HexDump( bytes, byte0, byteN )

    def GetName(self):
      return self.name

    def GetId(self):
       return self.id

    def IsCompatible(id):
       return id in self.compatiblelist
```

Here are two example derived classes, they would be in separate files.

```
# example: "all_decoders/protocol_1234.py"
class DogDecoder( DecoderBase ):
    def __init__():
        # pass important things to base constructor
        super( DecoderBase, self ).__init__("dog","Snoopy", ["beagle", "peanuts" ])

    def Decode( self, byte0, byteN ):
        Snoopy specific code goes here

# Example: "all_decoders/protocol_4321.py"
class CatDecoder( DecoderBase ):
    def __init__():
        # pass important things to base constructor
        super( DecoderBase, self ).__init__("cat","Garfield", ["fat-cat", "cartoon-cat" ])

    def Decode( self, byte0, byteN ):
        Garfield specific code goes here
```

Can somebody point me to some examples of how to (1) load modules as above and (2) they need to be derived classes and (3) how do I call these things?

[Note: Some edits, typos noticed after I clicked SUBMIT]

Comment: Try looking at the [`imp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html).

Comment: You might review this related: [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

1. To import a module given its path, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html .

*However*:

```
1a. a module's path is not ``foo/bar.py'`: it's `foo.bar`.  So:
      1aX first, drop the trailing `.py`
      1aY then, change slashes into dots
    both before passing the resulting string to 
   `importlib.import_module`

1b. when you import this way, you get a **module**, **not** a class!
    I recommend you just name each class `Decoder` within its module
    so you can just access it that way

1c. to make directory `foo` into a Python package, the directory
    **must** contain a file `__init__.py` (which can be empty).
```

There's no need for each `Decoder` class to be derived from the same base class; if you **want** it to be, for your convenience, put the base class in e.g `foo/base.py`, have each of the specific decoder modules start with `import .base`, and derive each Decoder class from `base.DecoderBase`.

So your code would be something like:

```
import importlib

def GetDecoderViaId( idnumber ):
    filename = "all_decoders/protocol_%04x.py" % idnumber

    # Pseudo code use default if special is not found
    if (!os.access(filename, os.R_OK)):
        filename = "all_decoders/protocol_DEFAULT.py"

    module_path = filename[:-3].replace('/', '.')
    themodule = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    theclass = themodule.Decoder
    return theclass
```

Remember to have an empty `all_decoders/__init__.py`, an `all_decoders.base.py` defining a `class DecoderBase`, and e.g

```
# in file: "all_decoders/protocol_1234.py"
import .base
class Decoder( base.DecoderBase ):
    def __init__():
        # pass important things to base constructor
        super( DecoderBase, self ).__init__("dog","Snoopy", ["beagle", "peanuts" ]

    def Decode( self, byte0, byteN ):
        Snoopy specific code goes here

# in file: "all_decoders/protocol_4321.py"
import .base
class Decoder( DecoderBase ):
    def __init__():
        # pass important things to base constructor
        super( DecoderBase, self ).__init__("cat","Garfield", ["fat-cat", "cartoon-cat" ]

    def Decode( self, byte0, byteN ):
        Garfield specific code goes here
```

The "how to call" is now trivial, e.g in the same Python module as `GetDecoderViaId`...:

```
theclass = GetDecoderViaId(theid)
aninstance = theclass(whatever, init, args, are, needed)
decoded = aninstance.Decode(byte0, byteN)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I do want the "baseclass".  I've seen that model before. Where exactly would the "base.py" file live?  For example:  decoders/protocol_1234/Decoder.py and  decoders/protocol_1234/__init__.py,  would  'base.py" be   decoders/base.py, or decoders/base/base.py?

Comment: @user3696153, why keep each decoder in a separate packages?  I'd have decoders/__init__.py (which you don't list), decoder/base.py, decoder/protocol_1234.py -- each decoder in a separate **module**, but all such modules in a single **package** `decoders`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a single package. The system needs to support users "dropping" new decoders into the system and it needs to be quite simplistic.  the framework can be complicated, but adding a new decoder must be simple.  Telling my "victim" to copy/clone a directory and modify it to make another decoder is simple.

Comment: @user3696153, how's it simpler for the user to copy/clone/modify a whole directory (`protocol_xyz/`... which must contain `__init__.py` and ...?) rather than a single file `protocol_xyz.py`?!   The latter task is simpler in any normal, accepted meaning of the word "simple"...!-)

Comment: Agreed. I see what you mean, sometimes I go down the wacky road. - BTW I'm making progress on this , thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok - stuck. If I call a base method, or derived method I get  "TypeError: unbound method Foo() must be called with Decoderbase as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: @user3696153, right -- you need to **instantiate** the class; I've edited the answer accordingly.  (If no init args are in fact needed, having classes just to instantiate a throw-away instance is pretty un-Pythonic, and simple decoder functions would probably be a better choice).

Answer (score 0):

working solution: Grazie very much Alexi

## File 1:   example/test.py

```
import importlib

def GetDecoder(name,xtra):
    theclass = importlib.import_module( 'Decoders.' + name )
    return theclass.Decoder(xtra)

sh = GetDecoder('snoopy', 'hockey');
sp = GetDecoder('snoopy', 'pilot');
g = GetDecoder('garfield', None );

print( "Snoopy Hocky says: %s" % sh.Decode( 3, 4 ) )
# This has an extra method
sh.Bark()

print( "SnoopyPilot says: %s" % sp.Decode( 5, 9 ) )
# And so does this one
sh.Bark()

print("Garfield says: %s " % g.Decode( 1,3 ))
# A different method
g.Purr()
```

## File 2: example/Decoders/**init**.py

```
#
# This file is empty
#
```

## File 3: example/Decoders/base.py

```
class DecoderBase(object):
    def __init__( self, n, idval ):
         self.name = n
         self.idcode = idval
         print( "Base created: %s %d " % (self.name, self.idcode));

    def GetName(self):
        return self.name

    def GetId(self):
        return self.idcode

    def Decode(self,b0,bn):
        msg = ("Decode from byte %d to %d" % (b0, bn ))
        return msg
```

## File 4: example/Decoders/snoopy.py

```
from base import DecoderBase

class Decoder( DecoderBase ):
    def __init__( self, varient ):
        self.costume = varient
        super( Decoder, self ).__init__( "Snoopy-" + varient, 0x444f47 );

    # Override the decoder
    def Decode( self, b0, b1 ):
        # but only if snoopy is playing hockey
        if self.costume == 'hockey':
            return ("Hockey decode: %d to %d" % (b0, b1))
        else:
            return super(Decoder,self).Decode( b0, b1 )

    def Bark(self):
        print "Barking(%s) ..." % self.costume
```

## File 5: example/Decoders/garfield.py

```
from  base import DecoderBase

class Decoder( DecoderBase ):
    def __init__(self, varient ):
        # Unlike snoopy decoder, garfield does not have any varients
        super( Decoder, self ).__init__( "Garfield", 0x434154 );

    # Override the decoder
    def Decode( self, b0, b1 ):
        return ("Garfield lasagna %d to %d" % (b0, b1))

    def Purr( self ):
        print "Purring like a cat.."
```

**END**