# How to dynamically import variables after executing python script from within another script

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.x, import

I want to extract a variable named `value` that is set in a second, arbitrarily chosen, python script.

The process works when do it manually in pyhton's interactive mode, but when I run the main script from the command line, `value` is not imported.

The main script's input arguments are already successfully forwarded, but `value` seems to be in the local scope of the executed script.

I already tried to define `value` in the main script, and I also tried to set its accessibility to global.

This is the script I have so far

```py
import sys
import getopt

def main(argv):
    try:
        (opts, args) = getopt.getopt(argv, "s:o:a:", ["script=", "operations=", "args="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(2)

    # script to be called
    script = ""

    # arguments that are expected by script
    operations = []
    argv = []

    for (opt, arg) in opts:

        if opt in ("-o", "--operations"):
            operations = arg.split(',')
            print("operations = '%s'" % str(operations))

        elif opt in ("-s", "--script"):
            script = arg;
            print("script = '%s'" % script)

        elif opt in ("-a", "--args"):
            argv = arg.split(',')
            print("arguments = '%s'" % str(argv))

    # script should define variable 'value'
    exec(open(script).read())
    print("Executed '%s'. Value is printed below." % script)
    print("Value = '%s'" % value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  Be specific.  Error type, message, unexpected behavior, whatever.

Comment: Have you tried `import` instead?  That's usually safer than `exec`.

Comment: @paidhima I edited the question. I meant, that value is not imported.

Comment: in case your import needs to be dynamic use `impmodule = __import__("modulename")` then refer to `value` via `impmodule.value`

Comment: I thought imports are always static. Thanks I'll try it out. If you're sure, you can already formulate an answer, I'll accept it then

Comment: You could get the value after the `exec` by using `locals()['value']`

Comment: @cdarke Thanks. I've just tried it out and it works!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/557406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` variable has been put into your locals dictionary by the `exec`, but was not visible to the compiler.  You can retrieve it like this:

```
print("Value = '%s'" % locals()['value'])
```

I would prefer an `import` solution

Answer (score 2):

In case your import needs to be dynamic, you can use

```
impmodule = __import__("modulename") # no .py suffix needed
```

then refer to `value` via

```
impmodule.value
```

There are several ways to achieve the same results.
See the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python) on this topic on SO

Comment: make sure to omit the .py suffix from the module filename you provide as an argument

Comment: I used the variable `script` as argument, so it includes the suffix, is that the error?

Comment: yes, I think so. Try hardcoding the module name without .py

Comment: @mike: `if script.endswith('.py'): script = script[:-3]`

Comment: The problem seems to be, that the imported script is missing a correctly set environment. It complains that `name 'operations' is not defined
`. There are more arguments that can be set in [\_\_import\_\_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Answer (score 1):

Using `locals()` as @cdarke suggested yielded the correct result!

```
exec(open(script).read())
print("Executed '%s'. Value is printed below." % script)

print("Value = '%s'" % locals()['value'])
```