# How can you import packages in a python for loop?

Tags: python, python-import

The following doesn't work, probably because packages is a list of strings. Is there any way to have such a loop in python?

```
    packages=['numpy','scipy']
    for p in packages:
        import p
```

Comment: The answer you seek is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python).  This question should probably be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Why? This is a really bad practice.

Comment: It's generally better not to, even though it is possible.

Comment: I was planning to put them in try-except block, so this would just save from extra lines. Why is this a bad practice @Morgan @Super?