# How to access variables from file passed through command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments

Currently I have `config.py` in my package and I can access variables defined in config.py from other py files as

```
import config
var1 = config.var1
```

First of all, Can I pass file as argument?
`test.py config.py`

But is there way to pass config file through command line as argument and access the variables defined in it? I see there is `sys` module to get arguments passed through command line. But can I get variables defined in passed file?

**edit**
Now I am able to access variables in passed file as `__import__(sys.argv[1])` and called `python test.py config`. But can I call config.py file by giving pythonpath? e/g/ `python test.py ~/Desktop/config` or `PYTHONPATH='~/Desktop/' python test.py config`? Because if I do this I get `no module error`.

Comment: Are you referring to command-line parameters, like `my_script.py a=1 b=abc d=1,23,5`?

Comment: Look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Comment: Just get the file name from sys.argv, then import the file and access the variables.

Comment: @ChadS.  I tried sys.argv but I get error `import by filename is not supported` I tried `__import__(sys.argv[1])` and passed `python test.py ./config.py`

Comment: @user2661518: What if you strip off the path prefix and the py suffix? Also, why not store the variables in a language agnostic way (e.g. JSON or XML) and use a Python library to read the variables from the file?

Comment: @DavidCullen Is there any specific library to read variables from file?

Comment: got it ! I ran it as `python test.py config` But how can call config file through path? e.g. `python test.py ~/Desktop/config`

Comment: Maybe what you want is https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do with `import config` is make all names from `config.py` available in your script.

You can do this using `__import__(sys.args[1])` like stated in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python).

But for actual program configuration, sure do take a look at the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module!

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="...")
p.add_argument("--var1", type=int)
p.add_argument("--var2", type=str)

config = p.parse_args() # will look at sys.args by default

if config.var1 > 10:
    ....
```

Comment: With `argparse`  you can't pass the file, right? I tried sys.argv but I get error `import by filename is not supported` I tried `__import__(sys.argv[1])` and passed python test.py ./config.py

Comment: got it ! I ran it as `python test.py config` But how can call config file through path? e.g. `python test.py ~/Desktop/config`

Comment: On windows, you can `set PATH=%PATH%;c:/dir/with/script`, and then you can run your script from anywhere.