# How to give path for file passed through command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I got answer for how to pass file as argument here [How to access variables from file passed through command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596823/how-to-access-variables-from-file-passed-through-command-line)

But I am asking separately since don't wanna mix two.
I am able to access variables in passed file as `__import__(sys.argv[1])` and called `python test.py config`. But can I call config.py file by giving pythonpath? e/g/ `python test.py ~/Desktop/config` or `PYTHONPATH='~/Desktop/' python test.py config`? Because if I do this I get `no module error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to import a python module using the `__import__` call. It only accepts the module name. If you need to add a directory to the `PYTHONPATH`, you can add it to `sys.path` and then import the module:

```
#File: ~/Projects/py/main.py

import sys

python_path = sys.argv[1]
module_name = sys.argv[2]

sys.path.insert(1, python_path)

print "Importing {} from {}".format(module_name, python_path)
__import__(module_name)
```

Now I created another file named `masnun.py` on `~/Desktop`:

```
# File: ~/Desktop/masnun.py

print "Thanks for importing masnun.py"
```

Now I try to run `main.py` like this:

```
python main.py ~/Desktop masnun
```

So I am passing the Python path as `argv[1]` and the module name as `argv[2]`. Now it works. I get this output:

[image]

Comment: this I can do in test.py But how can I declare pythonpath through command line because at command line I am running `python test.py config`

Comment: OK, I updated the answer with detailed codes and commands. Please see if it helps now.