# Run Python Function within each Python file in a directory

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to find a nice way to automate grading some students' code.  Each of the students is going to submit a file with a name something like `homework1_studentName.py`, and I'm going to download them all and put them in a folder.

Now each student should have a bunch of functions like `def question1(args):` in their file that I'm trying to grade. My goal is to make a grading script in that directory that iterates through each student's module, imports the code, runs the functions against some predefined test cases and then prints the output.  Is there a way to do this nicely?

It'd save a ton of time to just run the grading script once (after downloading all of their code) than to have to grade each file separately.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you import the module, you can access the functions dynamically using strings as follows:

```
import students_code

def run(function_name, module_name):
  getattr(module_name, function_name)()
  #this will call module_name.function_name()

run("question_1", students_code)
```

Maybe if you then had a config file for each assignment, you could automatically run things. You could also loop through `dir(the_module)` with this `run` function.

For testing their code automatically, check out: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html