# Using Python setattr to set an attribute reference to a method or function

Tags: python, setattr

I need to use setattr to read from a configuration file, and set an attribute of a class to a function in another module. Roughly, here's the issue.

This works:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number_cruncher = anothermodule.some_function

# method works like this, of course;
foo = MyClass()
foo.number_cruncher(inputs)
```

Ok, this is trivial, but what if I want to read the name of `some_function` from a configuration file? Reading the file and using setattr is also simple:

```
def read_ini(target):
    # file reading/parsing stuff here, so we effectively do:
    setattr(target, 'number_cruncher', 'anothermodule.some_function')

bar = MyClass()
read_ini(bar)
bar.number_cruncher(inputs)
```

This gives me a *'str' object is not callable* error. If I understand correctly, it is because in the first case I'm setting the attribute as a reference to the other module, but in the second case it is simply setting the attribute as a string.

Questions: 1) is my understanding of this error correct? 2) How can I use `setattr` to set the attribute to be a reference to the function rather than simply a string attribute?

I've looked at other questions and found similar questions, but nothing that seemed to address this exactly.

Comment: Is the module known ahead of time, or do you also need to load the module based on a string?

Comment: Are you saying that the value `anothermodule.some_function` is read from a file? If so, you are looking to use dynamic importing, and `getattr()` on the resulting module object to resolve that string into the function object.

Comment: Otherwise, if `anothermodule.some_function` is static (known at the time you write your code), then just use `etattr(target, 'number_cruncher', anothermodule.some_function)`. That third argument doesn't have to be a string, it is the actual object you want to use as the value for the attribute you are setting.

Comment: Edit: @MartijnPieters basically already said it... The third parameter to `setattr` is the value that you set, so if that is a string you set a string. If it's an int it will be an int etc and then ofc an object for an object.

Comment: module already known and imported. it's a library of possible functions, basically. looking at answers below but i think they've solved it.

Comment: If the other module is already known and imported, it's `target.number_cruncher = getattr(another_module, 'some_function')`. You only need `setattr` if the attribute name on the target is contained in a string rather than known at the time you write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most trivial approach would be something like:

```
module_name, function_name = "module.func".rsplit('.', 1)
f = getattr(sys.modules[module_name], function_name)
f()  # f is now callable, analogous to anothermodule.some_function in your code snippets.
```

Obviously, a lot potential issues are not addressed. First of all, it assumes that module is already imported. To address that you may refer to [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python) and use return value of `__import__`. Don't worry, CPython will optimize it internally and same module wouldn't be interpreted more than once.

Slightly better version would be:

```
module_name, function_name = "module.func".rsplit('.', 1)
f = getattr(__import__(module_name), function_name)
f()
```

Comment: For forward compat, probably best to use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) over `__import__`.

Comment: I understand this in concept, but how do I get `importlib.import_module` to simply import from another .py file in the same directory as my program? This is the way a simple `import whatever` would work, but I can't make sense of [link]https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module. I'm getting errors such as "No module named... xxx is not a module." How do I simply import from another .py file in the same directory as the program?

Comment: @user5747140 `import whatever` is equivalent to `whatever = importlib.import_module('whatever')`. Second argument (signature is `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`) is optional and allows you to use relative notation in `name` argument).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. When you use `setattr` you are setting the attribute to a string in your current example. So when you then call `bar.number_cruncher(inputs)` it correctly tells you that a string object is not callable. If instead you want to have `bar.number_chruncher` be the callable equivalent of the function `anothermodule.some_function`, then you can import it and set the function (not the string) as the attribute.

```
def read_ini(target):
    # file reading/parsing stuff here, so we effectively do:
    __import__("anothermodule.some_function") #Allows you to import based on a string parsed from your configuration file.
    setattr(target, 'number_cruncher', anothermodule.some_function)
```

Comment: that makes sense, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get 'anothermodule' to refer to a py file in the same directory as the program.