# Python: Dynamically import modules and objects

Tags: python, python-import

I want import dynamically some class through variable like:

```
classes = ['AaaBc', 'AccsAs', 'Asswwqq']
for class in classes:
    from file.models import class
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: What would be the point? What could you do with this that you couldn't do with just `import file`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__import__`

```
spam = __import__('spam', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

The statement import spam.ham results in this call:

```
spam = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

Note how `__import__()` returns the top-level module here because this is the object that is bound to a name by the import statement.

On the other hand, the statement `from spam.ham import eggs, sausage as saus` results in:

```
_temp = __import__('spam.ham', globals(), locals(), ['eggs', 'sausage'], 0)
eggs = _temp.eggs
saus = _temp.sausage
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__