# Dynamic equivalent of Python's "from <module> import <symbol>"

Tags: python, dynamic, runtime, python-import

In Python, it is possible to [dynamically import an entire module using `importlib.import_module(name)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301146/1391325), which returns the specified package or module (e.g. `pkg.mod`). However, is there no analogous way to dynamically import a specific function/class/etc. from a given module in the same fashion as done using e.g. [`from foo import bar`, where the symbol `bar` of the module `foo` is imported into the symbol table of the importing module?](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

For example, if I try to import a symbol directly using `importlib.import_module(symbol_name)`, I just get an `ImportError:`

```
import importlib

# Importing an entire module works fine
imported_module = importlib.import_module("os.path")
# This doesn't work
imported_symbol = importlib.import_module("os.path.basename")
```

Executing the code above prints the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stackoverflow/dev/importtest.py", line 6, in <module>
    symbol = importlib.import_module("basename", "os.path.basename")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'basename'
```

Comment: `itertools` does not have `import_module()`. The link that you mentioned contains `importlib.import_module` instead.

Comment: Thanks; I fixed the typo. Not sure how I managed that one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look up the symbol you need in the module object that is returned by `import_module` using `getattr`:

```
imported_module = importlib.import_module("os.path")
imported_symbol = getattr(imported_module, "basename")
```

Comment: Is this preferred to `imported_symbol = imported_module.basename` ? The question does not ask about `basename` as a string but hardcoded in the script.

Comment: No, it is not necessarily preferred. The dot notation and `getattr` do the same thing, except that `getattr` can have a default, which could be used for error checking etc. -- I'd normally do it with `getattr` because `"basename"` as a string mirrors using `"os.path"` as a string, and would  not trigger static analyzers that check module signatures etc.

Answer (score 2):

`import_module` method only accept module.

You could try something as below to access the module's method/attribute

```
imported_symbol = importlib.import_module("os.path").basename
```