# how to cycle module in python

Tags: python, module, cycle

There are many modules in a folder named schema

```
schema
   demo.py
   demo1.py
   xxx.py
```

my code here

```
import schema
for table in schema.__all__:
    do someting about table.xxx
```

I want to cyclic operate each module in schema, but table variable above code is a string, how can use the module with this table variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Comment: I'm not sure how good of an idea it is to rely on `__all__`, but you could always use `getattr(schema, table)` to return the actual attribute given a string from `table`.