# Dynamic import: How to import * from module name from variable?

Tags: python, python-import

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000967/248616), we can dynamically import a module using string variable.

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module('os.path')
```

My question is how to `import *` from string variable?

Some thing like this not working for now

```
importlib.import_module('os.path.*')
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? `*`-imports are generally frowned upon, they clutter the namespace and you may end up importing things you did not intend (e.g. a module is updated, gets a new function that overrides an earlier import). Do you have a concrete usecase for doing this dynamically?

Comment: I know using `import *` sound dangerous; though it works for simple use case. My concrete usecase is that I'm trying to use `proboscis` to run `python test` which allow me to pick up which test suit to run - the chosen test suit is defined by an array of test filenames.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do the following trick:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> globals().update(importlib.import_module('math').__dict__) 
>>> sin
<built-in function sin>
```

Be warned that makes all names in the module available locally, so it is slightly different than `*` because it doesn't start with `__all__` so for e.g. it  will also override `__name__`, `__package__`, `__loader__`, `__doc__`.

**Update:**

Here is a more precise and safer version as @mata pointed out in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492803/python-dynamic-import-how-to-import-from-module-name-from-variable#comment75980930_44492879):

```
module = importlib.import_module('math')

globals().update(
    {n: getattr(module, n) for n in module.__all__} if hasattr(module, '__all__') 
    else 
    {k: v for (k, v) in module.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')
})
```

Special thanks to Nam G VU for helping to make the answer more complete.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `it is slightly different than * because it doesn't start with __all__` - what is **it** here?

Comment: This will also import things like `__name__`, `__package__`, `__loader__`, `__doc__` etc. which you definitely do not want imported.

Comment: more than a sin

Comment: I see, may you update to clarify that and get accepted ^^ ?

Comment: `if not k.startswith('_')` would probably be better. The real import machinery when doing a `*` import also checks if the module has an `__all__` attribute and only imports what is given there.

Comment: Thanks for the trick! Looks better now, I just skipped `__all__` to make it a bit short snippet but your advice is good enough also to hide functions start with `_`

Comment: You two are brilliant!

Comment: @mata Lovely if you can help to modify @hurturk answer to include the `__all__` checking part. Thank you so much!

Comment: Something in the line of `module = importlib.import_module('math'); globals().update({n: getattr(module, n) for n in module.__all__} if hasattr(module, '__all__') else {k: v for (k, v) in module.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')})`, only [formatted nicer](https://pastebin.com/MiPwwjR8)

Comment: Hello, restructured the answer, please let me know if you want to keep previous one but I suppose this looks easier to read now. Thank you Nam G VU for your contribution.