# How to import variables from another file where the filename itself is a variable

Tags: python

If I have a file called `input_file.py` and I want to import some variables into another script I use the following:

```
from input_file import (VarA, VarB, VarC)
```

If I wanted to have the file name itself be a variable which I could easily switch how would I do it? As an example:

```
file_name = 'input_file'

from file_name import (VarA, VarB, VarC)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to clutter/clobber the global namespace and you should look at what @MatthewMoore pointed to.

Having said that, you can do this:

```
import importlib
globals().update(importlib.import_module(file_name).__dict__)
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492803/python-dynamic-import-how-to-import-from-module-name-from-variable/44492879#44492879).