# How can I achieve override a function call in the middle of another function?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am writing a Python3 program, in which I need to be able to override some method on the fly. My folder structure is more like:

```
./
prog.py
methods/
  add.py
  minus.py
```

In `prog.py` I want to call a `calc()` function which is defined both in `add.py` and `minus.py`. I wish that the code can work as if:

```
def prog('foo'):
    from method.foo import calc
    calc()
```

But importing in the middle of a function seems awful and might slow down the whole program. Is there any workaround that can achieve the same effect?

I am trying to be flexible so that I can add more methods later on, so I avoid if statements and import all the modules at once.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from just calling the functions in the branches of the if statement, or is it something more complicated than the example shows?

Comment: No, but I am thinking of add different calc() from time to time. In reality I hope to realize that prog(add) imports method.add without using if statements. I will modify my question... @BHustus

Comment: Ohh, so you want to be able to dynamically load a module from some path?

Comment: If you want to *dynamically import* something, there are some methods to do that at runtime. I'm not going to post this as a formal answer because I haven't tested this and I wouldn't recommend taking my word at face value, but look into [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and judicious use of `del`, see if that gets what you need.

Comment: That is correct... with out causing troubles.:) @BHustus

Comment: And for reference, [here is a question re: dynamic imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python). Your biggest concern, I think, would be name collisions if you include multiple modules with the same-named function. Hence, judicious use of `del` as a final statement in the function, *maybe*.

Comment: @BHustus: or, just use the module name as the target. And a dictionary, since the names are built dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Import the modules, and use the module name with `calc` attributes.
- Import the `calc` functions under alternate names with `from ... import ... as`

Either way, I'd store the function references in a dictionary, rather than use `if .. elif` to pick one.

The first approach

```
from method import add
from method import minus

calc_functions = {
    'add': add.calc,
    'minus': minus.calc,
}

def prog(method):
    return calc_functions[method]()
```

or the second:

```
from method.add import calc as addition
from method.minus import calc as subtraction

calc_functions = {
    'add': addition,
    'minus': subtraction,
}

def prog(method):
    return calc_functions[method]()
```

If you needed to import modules *dynamically*, then use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module), no need to worry about name clashes:

```
import importlib

def prog(method):
    try:
        calc_module = importlib.import_module('method.' + method)
    except ModuleNotFoundError:   # or ImportError in Python < 3.6
        raise ValueError('No such method {!r}'.format(method))
    return calc_module.calc()

    return calc_functions[method]()
```

Comment: This is neat, but in my case I will need to change the code every time I add some new calc() methods. Is it possible to do it dynamically?

Comment: @7O'clock: yes, you can import modules dynamically, see [Dynamic module import in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/301134)