# Import a python class from an upper directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a directory named `common` in the root directory of my project. Basically, there isn't a main file, but rather lots of scripts which I want to directly run.

What I want to do is something like that:

`from ../../common/ import <python_file>`

Is it possible without too much of a hustle?

Would I need to put `__init__.py` to make it work?

Comment: There is another way of doing it using [`imp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301298/1704235) module. However always use `virtualenv` as suggested by @Camille unless you have very specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of .. for imports is really a bad practice. What you should do is that. Create a virtualenv using `virtualenvwrapper` and then use `add2virtualenv common`

OR

Add the path of the root directory of your project into your `PYTHONPATH` env variable

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/of/my/project
```

An `__init__.py` file must be placed in every folder containing python code

Comment: Is there a third option? What is the common practice to import a `common` package? the suggested solutions seems like an hack to me (I'm a python newbie though)

Comment: Python developpers always use a virtualenv for their projects, its easy to use, and you MUST use it. I reccommand you to read this documentation https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/