# How bad is it to explicitly add things to locals()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to dynamically load modules as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000967/6378557).

I have written a script that requires some modules that may not be installed by default on some systems (such as `requests`). The script code assumes that a regular `import` has been done (it uses `requests.get`).

If I use the code in the link above, to import `requests` I would have to use:

```
requests=importlib.import_module('requests')
```

But this leads to a lot of code duplication since I have several modules. I can't use that in a loop since the variable name must change with the imported module.

I have found that I can use:

```
for m in list_of_modules:
    locals()[m]=importlib.import_module(m)
```

And everything happens as if I had done regular `import`'s.
(of course the real code catches exceptions...).

So the question is how valid/risky this is? Too good to be true or not? (Python 2.7 if that makes a difference)

Comment: Any reason why you're using `locals` instead of `globals`?

Comment: Also, note this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028743/7692463) in your linked thread, which is exactly what you propose. It seems like the community kinda accepted it (13 upvotes - 0 downvote)

Comment: This is a horrible idea; `locals()` is not guaranteed to be writable.  The proper way to handle an import of an optionally-installed module is to do it in a `try`...`except ImportError:` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicitely invalid. Doc of Python 2.7.15 says of `locals()` function:

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

`locals()` is a way for the program to know the list of variables in a function block. It is not a way to create local variables.

If you really need something like that, you can either use a local map, rely on the `sys.modules` map which is updated by `import_module`, or update the `globals()` map. Anyway, once a module was loaded, it exists (through the `sys.module` map) for the whole program, so it does not really make sense to store its reference in a local symbol table.

So if you really need to import a dynamically builded list of modules, I would do:

```
for m in list_of_modules:
    globals()[m]=importlib.import_module(m)
```

Comment: Good to know, glad I asked.