# How to dynamic import in python from path

Tags: python, module, python-import

I need to use dynamic import a module from a variable.

My problem is, that importing module is in directory.

Like this:

```
from A.B.C import D
```

How can I import dynamic?

Like this...

```
  module = __import__('A.B.{0}'.format('C'))
  my_class = getattr(module, 'D')
  instance = my_class()
```

I am getting a error: AttributeError: module 'A' has no attribute 'D'

Why?

Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

try using the import lib. The use of private functions is to the preferred way for loading modules.

```
module_object = importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

Is the location of your module part of the python path?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `fromlist` argument in order to import a specific module under a package:

```
module = __import__('A.B.{0}'.format('C'), fromlist=('D',))
instance = D()
```

Please refer to [`__import__`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) for more details.