# Dynamically load and execute Python modules in isolation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is an extension to the question posed here on dynamically execution of python modules

[Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

While the consensus seems to be to use **import** or importlib to accomplish the dynamic loading/execution of python modules, this solution tends to break down when you have additional imports defined inside of the dynamically loaded module.

Take the original example

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    commands/
        __init__.py
        command1.py
        command2.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

If command1.py imports command2.py then when you try to dynamically load command1.py using importlib or **import** it will fail with

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'command2'

Now I can get around this by adding commands directory to sys.path but that will pollute the global namespace. This can get even more problematic if there are multiple commands folder with different pip third party library dependencies. One command may depend on a different version of pip installed library than another command.

So in essence, I am looking for a way to dynamically load/execute a python module in isolation. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: `exec(f.read())`

Comment: How is exec different than importlib? Wouldn't it run into the same problems?

Answer (score 0):

Since `myapp` is your project's root folder, not `myapp/commands`, you should do:

```
from commands import command2
```

in `command1.py`, so that the interpreter will be able to load `command2.py`.