# (Python) Converting file values to dict

Tags: python

Help would be greatly appreciated with this as Im struggling with the final product.

I need to write a function that opens and reads the file, returns a dictionary where each key is the name of a function, and the value is a list of the parameters of the function. And should return something like this.

{"h":[x], "f":[a, b], "g":[c]}

The file I am transferring looks like this

def h(x):

```
   f(x + 4, 9)
```

def f(a, b):

```
    e = a * b
    g(e)
```

def g(c):

```
   b = 3
```

print(c)

print(b)

So far my code looks like this but I have no clue how to make it look like the final product in dictionary.

filename=""

ddd=dict()

new=list()

def take_name():

```
global filename

filename= input("Please, type the name of the file:")
```

print(take_name())

def open_read():

```
   global handle

   handle= open(filename, 'r')

   for line in handle:

       line=line.rstrip()

       if line.startswith('def'):

            line=line.replace('def', " ")

            line=line.replace(':', " ")


             new.append(line)



print(new)

print(ddd)
```

print(open_read())

Thanks again for the help

Comment: Please fix the formatting. Also, note that the "(Python)" shouldn't be in the title, that is what the tags are for.  [edit] you question to fix those two.

Answer (score 1):

Best to use Python's parser for the job, not regexps.

Assuming you mean `{'h': ['x'], 'f': ['a', 'b'], 'g': ['c']}` (since `{"h":[x], "f":[a, b], "g":[c]}` does not look particularly usable):

```
import ast

with open(filename) as f:
    code = f.read()
module = ast.parse(code, filename)
functions = { statement.name: [arg.arg for arg in statement.args.args]
    for statement in module.body if isinstance(statement, ast.FunctionDef)
}
print(functions)
```

However, this is just a base snippet, much more complexity is possible. For one, it will only give you top-level functions (you'd need some recursion to catch sub-functions, or methods). For another, it ignores the variety of possible arguments besides positional (e.g. `kwargs`). If you need them, you can add them yourself now that you see the basics of AST.

**EDIT:** A notable difference between `inspect` and `ast` is that you have to have imported (i.e. executed) the source file for it to be available to `inspect`; `ast` works on source file itself, without executing it. Both approaches are valid; but if you have security concerns about a file, or you cannot execute it (due to dependencies, for example), or if you want to fetch things you can't from executed code (such as locally defined functions I mentioned above), you should prefer `ast`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin python module **inspect** to accomplish what you want.
Here is some code to help you get started, in this example I am processing a file named dummy.py but you could use the import using something like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name)

```
import dummy
import inspect


members = inspect.getmembers(dummy)
for each in members:
    k,v = each
    if callable(v):
        args = inspect.getargspec(v)
        print(v, args)
```