# How can I import "random" in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I wanted to generate random numbers in RESTful API of Flask, so I tried importing "random" but there's an error.

```py
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request, url_for, random
    app = Flask(__name__)
    current_11 = random.uniform(2,5)
    voltage_11 = random.uniform(378,382)
    devices = [
    {
        'id': 11,
        'current': current_11,
        'voltage': voltage_11
    }
]
```

It says: ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from 'flask' (C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask__init__.py)
Does Flask not support "random"? Are there other ways to generate random numbers?

Comment: You don't import `random` from `flask`, you import it from the standard library. You need `import random` on a separate line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random` is not part of flask.

You need to do:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request, url_for
import random
```