# How to ask use input for what module to import?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a program that uses `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` to allow the user to select a .py file, and then import that file. I know that when you import a file, the code automatically runs, and that is what I am trying to do. Im am in Python 3 and the answer in [How to import a module given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name) does not work for me.

So far, I've tried getting the name of the file chosen and assigning it to a variable and then import it.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", 
filetypes = (("py files", "*.py"), ("all files", "*.*")))
file_to_import = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(name)[0])
import file_to_import
```

What I expected to happen is that Python imports whatever I chose, but instead, i get this Error message:

```
    import file_to_import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_to_import'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name)

Comment: `import file_to_import` will look for a file called "file_to_import" (that's how the interpreter interprets the statement). See the dupe for dynamic importing.