# How can I import specific files with names that I generated as strings in a function, and use its contents as global variables for my script

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, dynamic-variables

I would like to know how I can certain files based on generated variable names. **An important note is that all the variables defined in those files, should also be accessible within the environment of my current script.**

I've created a function, which should generate the names of the files that need to be imported in that specific case. Here's a simplified version of that function:

```
# the user provides these inputs: 
building_name = "cambridge"
room_name = "office1"


def determine_file_names(room=room_name, building=building_name):

    filename_building = "building_{}".format(building)    
    filename_room = "room_{}_{}".format(building, room)

    return(filename_building, filename_room)

building_file, room_file = determine_file_names()

# I'd like to import the files 'building_cambridge.py' and 'room_cambridge_office1.py' by doing the following: 
from Filefolder import building_file
from Filefolder import room_file
```

The problem is that the required files are not imported. I receive an error that the file location of 'building_file.py' is not found:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'building_file' from 'FileFolder' (unknown location)
```

It makes sense that it didn't find 'building_file.py', because I actually wanted python to import 'building_cambridge.py'.

I have about 300 files, of which only 2 specific ones need to be imported, so I have a dire need for a function like this to work. 
**I have a strong preference for the `import` statement, as that allows me to use all content (such as variables) in those files directly in my current script, rather than that I have to create 100s of different classes in those files.**

So again my question is: how can I ensure that I get to import the right files based on those generated variable names?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) (possible duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name)