# Passing package name and function name as variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a function defined in file `f1.py` as:

```
def fn1():
 return 1

def fn2():
 return 2
```

For learning exercise I am trying the following, which works:

```
import f1
from f1 import fn1, fn2
```

But the following approach doesn't work:

```
pkgName = 'f1'
fnName = 'fn1'
from pkgName import fnName
```

How can I pass package name and function name as variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Comment: I am not sure as I dont know how to implement the syntax for function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__import__` function to import the module first, and then access the function as an attribute of the module object with `getattr`:

```
module_name = 'f1'
function_name = 'fn1'
fn = getattr(__import__(module_name, fromlist=[function_name]), function_name)
fn()
```

Comment: This however doesn't work if my module_name = 'loc1.loc2.f1'. I know this is a bit tangential but I don't want to just start a new thread for this.