# Python 3, how to import modules from deep in a subdirectory tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a directory structure as follows

- mybasedir

  - mysub1

    - foo.py
  - mysub2

    - bar.py
  - mysub3

    - mysubderp3

      - foo.py

I would like to import every module under mybasedir which has a foo.py, any not import anything else (i.e. mysub2 shouldnt get imported as it has bar.py, not foo.py)

I would then like to be able to access the module as the < the directory containing foo.py >.foo
i.e. I want to use mysubderp3.foo instead of mysub3.mysubderp3.foo,

I have tried to walk the directory structure, looking for foo.py, and adding its path to __all__ in ./mybasedir/__init__.py,

i.e. `__all__ = ['mysub1', 'mysub3/mysubderp3']`

I would then import from some code as `from mybasedir import *`

This used to work in python 2.7, but doesnt seem to work in python 3.7

Does anyone have insight into how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could do several `sys.path.append(directory_absolute_path)`, one for every directory to search.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful reading [Examples in PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#nested-namespace-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Check out pathlib.Path.glob().

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

The example in the docs does a recursive search just as you describe. Once you have the file paths, you can use Path.parent to find the parent directories of each.

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt solve the problem of how to actually import the modules so they appear at the base namespace

Comment: Here is a helpful link on dynamic module imports. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string

It looks like you can use import lib for this.