# Alembic autogenerate empty migration file

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic, fastapi, starlette

I'm trying to connect the `alembic` library to the [databases](https://www.encode.io/databases/) and `sqlalchemy` libraries. As a guide, I use this example  [link](https://www.starlette.io/database/)

My projects file:

**db.py**

```
from databases import Database
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://....@localhost:5432/db"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = MetaData()

database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

**models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

from db import metadata

notes = Table(
    "notes",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("title", String(50)),
    Column("description", String(50)),
    Column("created_date", DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False),
)
```

**env.py** (alembic settings)

```
from db import DATABASE_URL, metadata

....
#add new
target_metadata = metadata
...
#change
def run_migrations_online():

    config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', str(DATABASE_URL))
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )
```

When I run

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'Add notest table'
```

the new file at migrations/versions this context is created

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I suppose it may be related to the use of the target_metadata = metadata variable. It seems to be all according to instructions, but the migrations do not work as expected.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone has a similar problem. All you have to do is import the tables from models.py into the env.py file before `metadata` object.

**env.py**

```
...
from models.notes import notes
from db import DATABASE_URL, metadata
...
```

Comment: If they are not imported those classes are never defined and metadata is never populated.

Comment: @GabrielCappelli but what shall I do in the case when I have dozens or even hundreds of models? Import all of them? Maybe there is a better way than `from mymodels import *`?

Comment: You could try to import those dynamically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string

Answer (score 1):

I have a different solution (or hit a different problem), in case anyone hits this problem. My issue was that the database had already been created and I was adding alembic afterwards. Because it was looking actively at the database and diffing it against the code I kept getting blank migrations. So creating an empty db as the starting point was able to then yield my initial migration.