# Python : importing a list from other file with exec()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a list from a file in python , and i don't know the name of the list or the file .

I am asking them in the code , and when I get them , i am trying to import the list ,

```
def listIMP(ITEM):
    listIMP = "from {0} import {1}".format(ITEM[0],', '.join(str(i) for i in ITEM[1:])) # generating command
    exec(listIMP) #exec generated command
```

I call it :

```
listN = input('!\n')# asking for list name
name = input('>') # asking for file name
name = name[:-3] #deleting .py
list1 = [name, listN] 
listIMP(list1) # calling my func
```

But i can't get the output , of exec , which is my list , i know i can get it as string but i would like to get it as list , is that possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Comment: your function runs `exec` with the default parameters. This passes `globals()` and `locals()` to their respective arguments. However, modifications to `locals()` will *not affect the actual local namespace*. There is almost certainly a better way, like using `imporlib` to import the module.

Comment: Note, imports inside a local scope only add names *to that local scope*. Your function with a hard-coded import statement wouldn't work the way you seem to desire for it to work anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) with [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead:

```
from importlib import import_module

def import_from(module, variable):
    return getattr(import_module(module), variable)

print(import_from('module_name', 'variable_name'))
```

`exec()` was not exactly made for what you're trying to achieve. Using it here will give you unnecessary headaches.

You might also find [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) useful: see [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

*Edit: replaced `__import__()` with `import_module()`. Usage of the former is discouraged.*