# Python import via exec does not work, while hardcoded import works

Tags: python, import, module, exec, eval

Inside a function, I have to import a variable (dict) from a module dynamically:

`exec("from ctrl_%s import default_settings" % get_version_id(iid))`

which doesnt work. When referencing this variable later, it says: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'default_settings' referenced before assignment`

The variable is in the global scope of the module to import.

But:

This all works, if I hardcode this statement without exec(). The string is correctly formed, I can print it out.

Someone knows what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly would discourage to use `exec` in the first place, it often does not do what you want especially if some special syntax is involved like here.

But fortunately there are some tricks:

e.g. you can import the module and use the **dict** or getattr:

```
import math 

getattr(math,"sin")                                                                                                                  

math.__dict__['sin']
```

Edit just checked my answer and I saw you wanted to import a module ...
But there is also a trick for this:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__

Look also at this question for some examples:
[How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Comment: thanks, this worked for now. First __import__, then getattr.