# How to automatically import new modules in python, based on the sys.argv?

Tags: python, import

Here's my situation, I have one management script, to initiate other classifiers. By creating new classifiers scripts, I need to add import [the classifier file name] to make it workable. Then I execute 'python managementfile.py -c ClassifierName' to make it run. Is there a possibility to make it execute "import Classifier" in python? The classifier name is arg from sys.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string