# Can you pass a variable to the import function of python?

Tags: python, function, file, import

i create a python file via the "with open()" method and now i would like to import the file but the filename should be variable.

```
filename = "Test"
with open(filename + ".py", "w+") as file:
    file.write("def main():\n\tpass")
```

Now at a other line in the skript i would like to import the python script called like filename. But you cant do something like:

```
import filename
```

because then python searches for a python script called "filename". but in this example it should import "Test.py". Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Answer (score 0):

You want the built in **import** function

```py
new_module = __import__(modulename)
```

so...

```py
filename = "Test"
with open(filename + ".py", "w+") as file:
    file.write("def main():\n\tpass")
new_module = __import__(filename)
```

Visit https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__