# Importing a daily changing variable name in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I want to import a file name which changes daily in python 3

File name >>> *filename_{day}.py*

`from filename_{day} import variable`

Comment: Okay mate, I stumbled on that module with some error and thought i was using the wrong one. now I will check again , thanks . Will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)  Specifically have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14000967/6400614