# How to import all files in path using python

Tags: python

I have a scenario where i am trying to import the contents in file and use it my script

I have a path : `/d/demo` in this path i have a `abc.py` file

This abc.py file contains some pre-defined parameters  that i need to use

Taking the filename into a variable : `varname`
Taking the filepath into a variable : `varpath`

**My script :**

```
import sys

varpath='/d/demo'
varname='abc'

sys.path.append(varpath)
from varname import *
```

This approach is not working  : The `from varname import *` is not replaced with filename like this `from abc import *`

Comment: If you want to import based on a runtime value like `varname`, you have to use the built-in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) package.

Comment: @0x5453  Can you demonstrate with an example

Comment: This thread has some examples: [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```py
import importlib
import sys

varpath = 'foo'
varname = 'bar'

sys.path.append(varpath)
bar = importlib.import_module(varname)
print(bar.baz)
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── bar.py
│   ├── __init__.py
└── main.py
```

with `bar.py` containing:

```py
baz = "Python"
```