# Using a variable in the code -> from variableX import abc - Python

Tags: python, variables, import, importerror

I am working on my python code in which I cannot figure out how to use a variable named 'x1' in the following line -

'''

```
import sys

x_1 = 'file_name'
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file2')

from x_1 import main
main()
```

'''

The place where I want to use the variable is in the place ->
from ***x1*** import main

It is giving an error that the module is not found. Please help me insert a variable in the place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a module given its name as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name-as-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`spec_from_file_location()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.spec_from_file_location) from the built-in `importlib` module *(introduced in python 3.1)*:

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("x_1", r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file2\file_name.py')
x_1 = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(x_1)
x_1.main()
```