# Python fails to use Dynamic variable with using HttpImport and throws "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named XXX"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, http, import

I'm trying to use HTTPImport dynamically in Python , consider the following code:

```
downloadFrom = '------------SOME-DOMAIN---------------'
globals()['downloadMe'] = 'EmployeeExampleClass'
print('downloadMe value is ===>>> ' , downloadMe ) ##### Prints: EmployeeExampleClass
     
with httpimport.remote_repo([downloadMe], downloadFrom):
        from downloadMe.model import EmployeeExample
```

This piece of code throws: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'downloadMe'`

How can we use a dynamic name when Importing modules with Python and `globals` ?

Comment: Any reason not to use `importlib` instead of manipulating `globals` dict?

Comment: @buran: Does it solve our problem ?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/301134/4046632

Comment: @buran: I can't understand how does it solve the above..

Comment: You need to import module in order to use it. Right now you jsut create a name `downloadMe` that is bound to a str literal `EmployeeExampleClass`. Put a side that `'EmployeeExampleClass'` is misleading name for package/module. From what you show it looks like you want to dynamically import module given it's name as string. At least that is what I understand from your post/snippet.

Comment: If you do `print(type(downloadMe))` you will see it's `<class 'str'>`

Comment: @buran: Yes , it is a string when I check the type , but when I try to use this string as a variable I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.