# How can I import .py file?

Tags: python

Below is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent,'public'))
import utilities 
sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.parent)
print(Path(__file__).parent.parent)
import publicmethods
```

I'm tring to import .py file in special directory. I can import `utilities.py` in `os.path.join(Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.parent,'public')` but can't import `publicmethods.py`. I'm sure the `publicmethods.py` under the `Path(__file__).parent.parent` directory.
What's wrong with it? Thanks!

ps: my dir structure like below:

```
c:\---
      |--projects
            |---spider
                   |---public
                   |      |---utilities.py
                   |---website
                          |--website
                                |-- publicmethods.py
                                |-- spiders
                                       |-- myspider.py
```

The code about import write in myspider.py

Comment: Could you please provide your dir structure?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956419/687896 , _may_ help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert it to `str` before inserting it in `sys.path`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
```