# How to import class from other directory following this structure python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading other posts I have structured my project as below:

```
/__init__.py
/src/main.py
/src/search-tree/node.py
/src/search-tree/multi_child_node.py
/src/utils/node_generator.py
```

Now when I'm inside `node_generator.py` I would like to import `multi_child_node.py` and use its class but I don't know how to do it, I have tried `from .x import y` but nothing. I'm new in python so maybe I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: `from ..search_tree.multi_child_node import *` and 'search-tree' should be with '_'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73947185/how-can-i-import-py-file)

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva Thanks! The problem is that I don't receive any suggestion from idle so I'm a little confused :S

Comment: @Bibhav no, it doesn't but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the file structure depends on where do you run your main file, not the file itself.

For example, if your `main.py` calls `node_generator.py` like this

```py
from utils import node_generator
```

and then `node_generator.py` calls `multi_child_node.py`, it should call it as it was called from `main.py`:

```py
from search_tree import multi_child_node
```

P.S, you shouldn't use dash `-` or spaces in the naming for your module, but if you have to, check out the answer for this question [How to import module when module name has a '-' dash or hyphen in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it)